# Installation failed for Symfony3 RoutingBundle

Tags: php, symfony

Does the RoutingBundle even work for Symfony3?  I tried to install it and got some weird errors:

```
$ php composer.phar require symfony-cmf/routing-bundle
Using version ^1.4 for symfony-cmf/routing-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

And then this whole bit came right after:

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for symfony-cmf/routing-bundle ^1.4 -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/routing-bundle[1.4.0].
>       - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.0.4
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.4
>       - symfony-cmf/routing-bundle 1.4.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21,...
>
> - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.4
> - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.4
> - Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v3.0.4, required as 3.0.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.4].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

What I need is to have a dynamic router such that *most* requests (unless they match a different specific route) will go through one bundle/controller/action.

I tried just changing the routing.yml for my bundle like this:

```
mybundle_homepage:
    path:     /{page}
    defaults: { _controller: MybundleBundle:Default:index }
    requirements:
        path: ".+"
```

So that any route domain.dev/page/another-page/yet-another-sub-page... would go to this controller.  (Hope that makes sense)

And that didn't work either.  What am I missing?

Comment: The SymfonyCMF RoutingBundle is not compatible with Symfony 3 yet. The Routing component which comes with the `ChainRouter` and `DynamicRouter` classes is. Maybe you can integrate them directly in your application as a workaround.

Comment: Just found https://github.com/symfony-cmf/routing-bundle/issues/317.

Comment: @xabbuh this should be posted as an answer ;)

Comment: I still do not get why something like this is not possible to do with the standard symfony 3 Routing. But probably I'm missing something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SymfonyCMF RoutingBundle is not compatible with Symfony 3 yet (see https://github.com/symfony-cmf/routing-bundle/issues/317). The Routing component which comes with the ChainRouter and DynamicRouter classes is. Maybe you can integrate them directly in your application as a workaround.

Comment: Any idea on how I could integrate those?  Which files would I need exactly?  (I'm new to symfony) And thanks for the response!

Comment: Sorry, not really. You can take a look at the existing bundle how they did it there. Maybe that is of any help.